# how to resolve invalidSubquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$to=$_POST['to'];
$from=$_POST['from'];
$repeat=$_POST['repeat'];


  $mysqlquery= mysql_query("select count(patient_id) as idpateint,patient_id from patient where STR_TO_DATE(date_enter,'%d/%m/%Y' ) between STR_TO_DATE( '$repeat','%d/%m/%Y' ) and STR_TO_DATE('$to','%d/%m/%Y') and patient_type='opd' and patient_id = (select patient_opd  from patient where STR_TO_DATE(date_enter,'%d/%m/%Y' ) between STR_TO_DATE( '$from','%d/%m/%Y' ) and STR_TO_DATE('$to','%d/%m/%Y') and patient_type='opd')")or die('invalid'.mysql_error());
      while($mysqlquery1=mysql_fetch_array($mysqlquery)){
    echo $mysqlquery1['idpateint']; 
     }
```

This is the sql query. I am getting how to resolve the problem . kindly anyone help to resolve the problem .thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change to an `IN` match instead.

```
... and patient_id IN (select patient_opd ...
                   ^^----
```

`=`-type equality testing is purely for single-value to single-value comparisons, e.g.

```
 42 = 42
```

Your subquery returned multiple records, meaning the DB was trying to do

```
 42 = 42,107,etc....
```

Comment: is there any other solution ?? bcz i m getting output as 0.

Comment: maybe it's `$myslquery1['idpatient']`? No idea. Try `var_dump($mysqlquery1)` to see what you're really getting.

Comment: $mysqlquery= mysql_query("select count(patient_id) as idpateint,patient_id from patient where STR_TO_DATE(date_enter,'%d/%m/%Y' ) between STR_TO_DATE( '$repeat','%d/%m/%Y' ) and STR_TO_DATE('$to','%d/%m/%Y') and patient_type='opd' and patient_id in (select patient_id  from patient where patient_type='opd' and STR_TO_DATE(date_enter,'%d/%m/%Y' ) between   STR_TO_DATE( '$from','%d/%m/%Y' ) and STR_TO_DATE('$to','%d/%m/%Y') )")or die('invalid'.mysql_error());
      while($mysqlquery1=mysql_fetch_array($mysqlquery)){
    echo $mysqlquery1['idpateint'];
     }  Notice: Undefined variable: repeat